# Parse last added Facebook like-buttons

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I have an infinite scroll which fetches new elements including like-buttons for each new element, but as of now it rund FB.XFBML.parse(); for ALL like-buttons on page.

Is it possible to run this for the last added only?

HTML:

```
<div id="stream">
    <ul>
        <li>Likebutton</li>
        <li>Likebutton</li>
        <li>Likebutton</li>
        <li>Likebutton</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function lastAddedLiveFunc() {
    infiniteSorting = $('#infiniteSorting').val()
    totalRows = $('#totalRows').val()
    offset = $('.item').length - 1;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'infinity.php',
        data: {
            'offset': offset,
                'total': totalRows,
                'sorting': infiniteSorting
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#stream').append(data);
            if (data == "") {
                $('div#loader').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('div#loader').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

And from the infinity.php we get:

```
<li>Likebutton</li>
```

I want to only do the Parse of this element and not the ones that is already on the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can pass a specific DOM node under which the method will look for new elements to parse as paramater: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: thanks! I forgot to mention. But each new element have all class="item" so then it won't do it for the new ones, or am I totaly wrong now?

Comment: Well you should be able to select just the last one added easily with jQuery … but don’t forget, the parse method wants a DOM node reference, not a jQuery object as parameter, so you’ll have to de-reference it (`$("whatever")[0]`).